# Best container for dictionary in STL

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

What is the best container in STL for a dictionary?
The dictionary will accept the words from a file that does not have duplicates.
The primary use is word search.
thanks...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: if there arent any duplicates, then simply use a `std::vector`

Comment: @tobi303 searching for a word in a vector that contains 1 millions words is probably not very fast.

Comment: The efficiency of vector search is not low compared to set ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz true, vector has worse insert and find complexity. For small sizes I would measure first.

Comment: If you have a sorted vector, and you have a custom find function then it'll perform just fine - but if you're going to that length, you may as well just use a set.

Comment: @בונםגשייד I took the freedom to interpret "best" as "most simple" thats where my comment was coming from. If you are concerned about max efficiency you have to measure anyhow (instead of blindly relying on big-O complexities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to check for an existence of the word, [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) is the container you're looking for. If you would like to keep the translation with the original word (key - value), you should use the [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) container.
Both set and map are standard STL containers.

Answer (score 4):

[std::unordered_map](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is not part of the STL but part of the Standard Library. The STL has a map which is almost the same.

Comment: At least one guy who gets STL correctly. Have an upvote for that.

Answer (score 0):

The best container is the one you measured being the best.

Try `unordered_set`, `set` and sorted `vector` with `binary_search`.